# Jquery crossfade light plugin :: Why this code not working in IE6+7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Why [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/eLBPE/1/) not working in IE6+7?(my code)

I check on ie 6+7 - not working after I check that the code working in Firefox + ie8.

This simple jquery light plugin that switch pictures by cross-fade effect.

```
   (function( $ ){

        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.sliderBox').CrossFadeSlider();
        });


     $.fn. CrossFadeSlider=function(options){
         //default settinfs
         var settings={
          pagingWrapperClass: 'controls',
          slideWrapperClass:'slider',
          pagingWrapperElement:$('.controls'),
          slideWrapperElement:$('.slider'),
          slideTag: "li",
          pagingTag:"li",
          width:'790px',
          height:'286px',
          slideInterval:4000,//Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
          autoplay:true
         };

         $.extend(settings, options);
         //set slide size
         this.css('width',settings.width).css('height',settings.height);
         //Add Default classes or it can be dome manually in code.
         settings.pagingWrapperElement.addClass(settings.pagingWrapperClass);
         settings.slideWrapperElement.addClass(settings.slideWrapperClass);
         //create paging
         var strPaging='';
         settings.slideWrapperElement.children().each(
            function(i,el){
               strPaging=strPaging+'<'+settings.pagingTag+'><a href="#'+$(this).attr("id")+'">'+(i+1)+'</a></'+settings.pagingTag+'>';
            }
       );

         settings.pagingWrapperElement.append(strPaging);

         //Set Default State of paging
         $("."+settings.pagingWrapperClass).show();
         $("."+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag+":first").addClass("active");
         var active = $('.'+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag+'.active');
         var activeBefore = active;
         //Set Default State of slides
         $("."+settings.slideWrapperClass+" "+settings.slideTag).css('display','none');
         $("."+settings.slideWrapperClass+" "+settings.slideTag+":first").css('display','block');
         $("."+settings.slideWrapperClass+" "+settings.slideTag).css("background-color", "transparent");
         $("."+settings.slideWrapperClass+" "+settings.slideTag+" img").css("background-color", "transparent");

         //Paging + Slider Function
         var rotate = function(){

             activeBefore.removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
             active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

             $(activeBefore.find('a').attr('href')).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                 $(this).css('display','none');
             });

             $(active.find('a').attr('href')).fadeIn('normal',function(){
                 //$(this).css('display','block');
             });
         };

         //Rotation + Timing Event
         var rotateSwitch = function(){
             play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
                 activeBefore=$('.'+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag+'.active');
                 active = activeBefore.next();
                 if ( active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                     active = $('.'+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag+':first'); //go back to first
                 }
                 rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
             }, settings.slideInterval); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
         };

         rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

         //On Hover
         $("."+settings.slideWrapperClass+" "+settings.slideTag).hover(function() {
             clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
         }, function() {
             rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
         });

         //On Click
         $("."+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag).click(function() {
             active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
             activeBefore=$("."+settings.pagingWrapperClass+" "+settings.pagingTag+'.active');
             //not doing nothing if active button pressed.
             if(active.get(0)===activeBefore.get(0)){return false;}
             //Reset Timer
             clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
             rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
             rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
             return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
         });
     };
     })( jQuery );
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in IE9 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the way IE implements the href attribute.  Instead of returning the actual href value you want, which is something like #slide3, it's returning the absolute path like http://mysite.com/#slide3.  The easy way to deal with this is the split the string and just extract the actual anchor tag you want, which works in all browsers.  Here is what I changed your rotate javascript function to:

```
                 var rotate = function () {

                     activeBefore.removeClass('active'); 
                     active.addClass('active');
                     var href = activeBefore.find('a').attr('href');
                     href = href.split('#');
                     $('#' + href[href.length-1]).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                     $(this).css('display','none');
                 });

                    href = active.find('a').attr('href');
                    href = href.split('#');
                    $('#' + href[href.length -1]).fadeIn('normal',function(){
                     //$(this).css('display','block');
                 });

                 };
```

Here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eLBPE/3/

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem is that you shouldn't put script tags in the script box. You have it set to onLoad so it takes everything in the textbox and places inside the onLoad function.

So place the script tag for jquery in the head in the html box instead. Then remove the other script tag.

I also moved you document.ready function to then end and got it "working" in IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/pTcXB/. The images are not being replaced in IE event though the rotation work.

I'm pretty sure the reason is here:

```
$(activeBefore.find('a').attr('href')).fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

IE7 atleast is a bit tricky when it comes to url's. It might be jquery specific but I never write plain javascript anymore so I'm not sure. If you add a link to the dom like elem.append('') that href will be http://www.blablabla.bla#something. Knowing that you can solve it in two way. Either add the link and then set the href by elem.attr('href', '#something') or you can split and the hash and build the url from there.

I tried the second approach and got it working(only tested IE7 through the IE9 emulator) http://jsfiddle.net/pTcXB/8/

Comment: Are you running the real IE7. Because it certainly works for me in IE9 wih Browser mode: IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 Standards. It could be some differences in the emulation

Comment: i running real ie7 - the pic not change

Comment: Do the links rotate? If so try uncommenting the alert I placed before the rows shown above and make sure it alerts #something

Comment: Sorry, I posted pretty much the same solution you did in your second part, should have read your explanation more closely rather than just the comments.  Voting up.